# java.io.UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes0(Native Method)

Tags: linux, nginx, centos, tomcat, mod-jk

My OS=CentOS
Jdk + Tomcat 8.5 + mod_jk connector

Here is error:

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report

Message Servlet execution threw an exception

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Root Cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError
    java.io.UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes0(Native Method)
    java.io.UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes(UnixFileSystem.java:242)
    java.io.File.exists(File.java:819)
    sun.misc.URLClassPath$FileLoader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:1282)
    sun.misc.URLClassPath$FileLoader.findResource(URLClassPath.java:1249)
    sun.misc.URLClassPath$1.next(URLClassPath.java:267)
    sun.misc.URLClassPath$1.hasMoreElements(URLClassPath.java:277)
    java.net.URLClassLoader$3$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:601)
    java.net.URLClassLoader$3$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:599)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    java.net.URLClassLoader$3.next(URLClassLoader.java:598)
    java.net.URLClassLoader$3.hasMoreElements(URLClassLoader.java:623)
    sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.next(CompoundEnumeration.java:45)
    sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.hasMoreElements(CompoundEnumeration.java:54)
    sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.next(CompoundEnumeration.java:45)
    sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.hasMoreElements(CompoundEnumeration.java:54)
    javax.mail.Session$5.run(Session.java:1209)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    javax.mail.Session.getResources(Session.java:1202)
    javax.mail.Session.loadAllResources(Session.java:1118)
    javax.mail.Session.loadProviders(Session.java:886)
    javax.mail.Session.<init>(Session.java:210)
    javax.mail.Session.getInstance(Session.java:232)
```

**UPDATE-1**
Is it problem of connecting oracle 18c? I seen one similar this [LINK](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-37044)

Please advise

Comment: *Please advise* OK:  provide more information.  The data you provided is not enough for anyone to even guess what your problem is, much less provide a solution.

Comment: @AndrewHenle The websites are down and either displaying above error or 504 Gateway Time-out. What more information I can provide? Please advise so that I can post it?